# What are Top-Level Frames in web browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, httpwebrequest, frame, toplevel

I'm creating a Chrome Web Extension, which uses the [chrome.webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/) to intercept and alter HTTPS requests.

Within their documentation, Google talk about different request types. One of these types is `main_frame`, which is a request for *"a document that is loaded for a top-level frame"*.

To me this implies that Chrome treats everything as an iframe, but that doesn't seem right. What is the meaning of the *"top-level frame"* terminology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame terminology is used to describe part of the Chrome browser's rendering process. Please see this article on [Rendering Architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/renderingng-architecture/) for more information.

From the article, a frame contains:

1. DOM state,
2. CSS,
3. Canvases,
4. External resources, such as images, video, fonts, and SVG.

Therefore, a frame is a complete HTML document plus the document's URL.

It's actually correct to consider everything as an iframe, because that's how the Chrome browser views web pages when it's rendering them. The *"top-level-frame"* is the uppermost frame in a *"frame hierarchy"*, and contains the information retrieved from the initial URL request. Any other frames, for example, iframes, are child frames of this *"top-level-frame"*.

As an interesting aside, for performance purposes, frames from different websites are dealt with by different rendering processes. This is why your main web page (top-level-frame) can load quickly, whilst your iframe (child-frame) takes a few seconds.